# JQuery Show Set of Fields based on Dropdown Value

Tags: jquery, html

I have an HTML form which has a field with an ID of 'soln_c_links' this is a selection field with two values 'Yes' and 'No';

Below this field are 4 table rows with input fields that based on the selection above I would like to show / hide. The issue i have is there is no DIV with an ID surrounding theses fields and in addition there is not an ID in the **tr** to grab on to, and as this is a precompiled software I am unable to change this.

The fields do have two elements within the **tr**... (Example)

```
<tr>
<td>
<SPAN id=_Captsoln_c_title_a class=VIEWBOXCAPTION>Link Title:</SPAN><BR>
<SPAN id=_Datasoln_c_title_a class=VIEWBOX>
<INPUT id=soln_c_title_a class=EDIT maxLength=20 size=50 name=soln_c_title_a>
<INPUT type=hidden name=_HIDDENsoln_c_title_a></SPAN>
</td>
</tr>
```

All of the four rows do follow the same naming convention i.e. soln_c_title_a and soln_c_link_a these go from 'a' to 'd'

Is this possible to achieve using JQuery?

Thanks

Justin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to select the table row, you can select its child and then bubble up to the parent.

Example:

```
$(".VIEWBOX").each(function() {  //this selects the VIEWbox class elements

     var row = $(this).parent().parent(); //The DOM is TR > TD > ".VIEWBOX"-item

    if(selector here)
        row.hide();
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use the [n-th child selector](http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/) instead. Example to hide the first row use:

```
$('table tr:nth-child(0)').hide();
```

Of course you need a way to identify the table. That might be possible using [`closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) or [`next()`](http://api.jquery.com/next/) depending on your JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have any ID or any easier way of finding out the correct INPUT element you are looking for you can always perform the lookup based on it's name

```
$('input[name=_HIDDENsoln_c_title_a]')
```

the name can also be generated by your code, so if you need to alter the name of your dropdown value to match the field value you can also do it

```
var altName = ... // some text variations on the name
$('input[name=' + altName + '])
```

You can also match names beginning with specified text

```
$('input[name$=someStartText]')
```

ending with specified text

```
$('input[name^=someEndText]')
```

containing specified text

```
$('input[name*=someText]')
```

or even containing a specific word (delimited by spaces)

```
$('input[name~=someWord]')
```

Comment: Excellent thanks for this so I would just set the visible function to these as they are found?